# How to limit access to zookeeper except for acl?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We have deployed a zookeeper cluster and already have some data. Now we need limit the access to zookeeper to ensure safety.
As far as I known, we can set acl for existing znodes. But can we limit access to zookeeper service not by acl? If so, we don't need change the acl of every znode.
It seems that zookeeper authentication is always together with acl.